# saving a screen shot in watir

Tags: watir

I want to save screenshot in Watir with a filename like `ddmmyyyy_hhmmss.png`.

I am trying following...

```
@@filename = Time.now
browser.screenshot.save (@@filename.png)
```

...but it saves file as `@@filename.png`. Also I need to save file in particular location.

Could you please help me out?

---

Hello Zeljko,

I tried your suggestion, but I am getting following error message:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `initialize': Invalid argument - 2013-01-03 11:02:21 +1100.png (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensio
ns/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensio
ns/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `save_screenshot'
```

I think the issue is format of the date and time stamp.

Comment: Why are you using class variable `@@filename` instead of local variable `filename`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.screenshot.save ("#{@@filename}.png")
```

If you want to save the file in a particular location, try this:

```
browser.screenshot.save ("/path/to/file/#{@@filename}.png")
```

Of course, replace `/path/to/file/` with the actual path.

Comment: Hello, Zeljko, I have edited my question. Could you please have a look.

Comment: Looks like you have fixed the problem.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Browser to see other possible calls, e.g. `#png` to get base 64 encoded png image.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help.

I used following to format the date and time part and now it is saving screen-shot in required location.

filename = DateTime.now.strftime("%d%b%Y%H%M%S")

browser.screenshot.save ("Test/ #{filename}.png")

Regards